# Copy to Clipboard with font style

Tags: javascript, html

I'm looking for a way to copy some div text with JavaScript copying the style (italics, font family, size, etc.) so I can paste it into Word and look the same as the page.

If I want to copy this text:

"*Hello* world"

I want to paste as the same and not:

```
"<i>Hello</i> world"
```

I don't know how and appreciate your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, when you copy text from a web browser, what you copy is only the text. The appliance of any style is job of the web browser. 
Now, in this case though, styles can be applied into a Word document, so what you can is to first of all copy the plain text without the styles to Word. 
Then, you can make CSS file with all the styles that you want to apply into this document(Grouping all your styles in css files is a generally good practice, instead of using  or  and so on..).
 Then, you can apply this style into the document. Now because obviously your question might be: "How do I apply the style into the document?", there has already be done a discussion about that here: https://superuser.com/questions/65107/how-to-apply-external-css-stylesheet-to-document-in-microsoft-word

Hope it helped!

Comment: Thanks, i did this https://jsfiddle.net/zhen4baz/
That's the only way to do what i want

Comment: Oh, pretty imporessive! I didn't know you could do something like that in javascript.

Comment: Well, who uses safari? :P OK, I am joking but you know it's better than not working in Chrome.

Comment: I thought the same but a lot of people who uses iOS use Safari, but i'm looking for another solution. Thanks anyway for your help (:

Comment: Nothing, anyway you are the one to teach me something here! Good luck in finding the solution!