# How to copy text with particular font-face and size to Clipboard using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to know if it would be possible to set a specific font-face and font size when copying text to clipboard from the following element displayed on a web page:

```
<div class="box" id="copy"...></div>
```

by using button:

```
<button onclick="copyToClipboard('#copy')">Copy Text</button>
```

supported by the following javascript bit:

```
 <script>
 function copyToClipboard(element) {
 var $temp = $("<input>");
 $("body").append($temp);
 $temp.val($(element).text()).select();
 document.execCommand("copy");
 $temp.remove();
 }
 </script>
```

At the moment i'm able to copy but only with default font and font size. I need it as Times, 14pt. Any suggestions how to achieve it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33425077/copy-to-clipboard-with-font-style solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the snippet I came up with:

```js
function copy() {
  var text = document.getElementById("copy")
  var range, selection
  selection = window.getSelection()
  range = document.createRange()
  range.selectNodeContents(text)
  selection.removeAllRanges()
  selection.addRange(range)
  document.execCommand('copy')
  window.getSelection().removeAllRanges()
}
```

```css
#copy {
  font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<div id="copy">Hi</div>
<button onclick="copy()">Copy</button>
```

It simply copies the text from the div, preserving the formatting from the styles given.